# Check if an array it not a indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

I need check if a specific Array is *keyed* or indexed. For instance:

```
// Key defined array
array('data-test' => true, 'data-object' => false);

// Indexed array
array('hello', 'world');
```

I can easily do a `foreach` with the array keys to check if all is integer. But exists a correct way to check it? A built-in PHP function?

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

```
// function is_array_index($array_test);
//    $array_test = array('data-test' => true, 'data-object' => false);

foreach(array_keys($array_test) as $array_key) {
    if(!is_numeric($array_key)) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function is_indexed($arr) {
  return (bool) count( array_filter( array_keys($arr), 'is_string') );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is from [php.net function.is-array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-array.php):

```
function is_assoc($array) {
    return (is_array($array) && 0 !== count(array_diff_key($array, array_keys(array_keys($array)))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
function isAssoc($arr)
{
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the key `[0]`:

```
$arr_str = array('data-test' => true, 'data-object' => false);

$arr_idx = array('hello', 'world');

if(isset($arr_str[0])){ echo 'index'; } else { echo 'string'; }

echo "\n";

if(isset($arr_idx[0])){ echo 'index'; } else { echo 'string'; }
```

Example: http://codepad.org/bxCum7fU